# updating package.json to add android to react native

Tags: android, json, react-native

I have a ios react native app and I would like to add the android part to it.

I do not understand this line in the docs

Update the react-native dependency in your package.json file to the latest version

Currently my package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "sassi",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-icons": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-splashscreen": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"react-native dependency"* is the part which indicates the react-native version you're working with.

In your case it's 0.15.0: `"react-native": "^0.15.0"`.

The latest version of react native at the moment is [0.18](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.18.0-rc), so according to the recommendation that you've mentioned, you should change the version to: `"react-native": "^0.18.0"`.

You'll then need to run `npm update` to update the package.

Comment: After U run the android I get the following error

To run your app on Android:
   Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected
   cd /Users/adamkatz/Projects/react-native/sassi
   react-native run-android


New android projects run fine

Comment: I don't know why you are getting this error. But maybe you should just create a new project using "react-native init" and just move your files there?

Comment: I restarted my computer and now it magically works, no idea why but I will accept it

Answer (score 3):

the best way is

in console write `npm outdated`
this command show you the latest version that you need update
and you need modified your current version in your package.json with latest version and save

after write in console `npm update --save`